# MySql: Error code 1422, Explicit or implicit commit is not allowed in stored function or trigger

Tags: mysql

I have created three tables  MySql named

1. r_sisl_purpurchae.
2. r_mil_pur.
3. mv_purchase_data.

Then I created an **stored procedure** named **purchase_data_mv_update**  which truncates data of **mv_purchase_data**
table and insert values from tables **r_sisl_purpurchase** and **r_mil_pur**.
its script is as below

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE purchase_data_mv_update ()
    BEGIN
        TRUNCATE TABLE mv_purchase_data;
        INSERT INTO mv_purchase_data 
(unit_code, season_cntrl, ryot_code, purchy_number, mill_purchy, vrt_code,vgrp_code, token_date, token_time, gross_date, gross_time,
    tare_date, tare_time, gross, tare, net, joona, amount, vehicle_code, society, tran_type, for_unit, token_type
)
SELECT 
    unitcode AS unit_code, season AS season_cntrl, ryot_code, s_purchy AS purchy_number, m_purchy AS mill_pur_no, vrt_Code, vgrp_code,
    arr_date AS token_date, arr_time AS token_time, gross_date, gross_time, tran_date AS tare_date, TIME AS tare_time, gross, tare, net, 
    (gross-tare)joona, amount, p_mode MODE, soc_code, tran_type, CONCAT('0',SUBSTR(s_purchy,1,1)) forunit, '0' token_type
    FROM r_sisl_purpurchase
UNION ALL   
SELECT a.unit_code, a.season_cntrl, a.m_grower ryot_code, a.m_ind_no, a.mill_pur_no, a.`m_var` vrt_code, a.`m_categ` vgrp_code,
    b.tk_date token_date, b.tk_time token_time, c.gr_date gross_date, c.gr_time gr_time, a.m_tare_dt tare_date, a.m_tare_tm tare_time,
    a.`m_gross` gross, a.`m_tare` tare, (a.m_gross-a.m_tare-a.m_joona) net, a.`m_joona` joona, a.`m_amount`, a.`m_vehicle_mode` MODE,
    a.`m_society_no`, '1' tran_type, a.`for_unit_code`, a.m_tk_type token_type
FROM r_mil_pur a, r_token b, r_gross c
WHERE a.`unit_code` = b.`unit_code`
AND a.`unit_code` = c.`unit_code`
AND a.`season_cntrl` = b.`season_cntrl`
AND a.`season_cntrl` = c.`season_cntrl`
AND a.`m_ind_no` = b.`tk_indno`
AND a.`m_ind_no` = c.`gr_ind_no`;
END
//
```

and to run this procedure I have created a **Trigger**

```
Delimiter $$
Create Trigger run_proc_purchase_data_mv_centre_insert AFTER INSERT ON 'r_sisl_purpurchase' 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   CALL purchase_data_mv_update;
END;
$$
```

Now when I am inserting data in **r_sisl_purpurchase** table it shows an error message: **Error code: 1422 Explicit or implicit commit is not allowed in stored function or trigger**

and  if I drop trigger and run stored procedure manually  `CALL purchase_data_mv_update` then it is inserting values in **mv_purchase_data**

Comment: `truncate` implicitly commits. But as *Explicit or implicit commit is not allowed in stored function or trigger*, it threw an error.

Comment: Can't you use DELETE instead of TRUNCATE? TRUNCATE is also quite expensive in InnoDB.